# Word difference between 'proficient' , 'competent' and 'accomplished'

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference

> Is there any difference between '**proficient**' , '**competent**' 
>   and '**accomplished**' in 'when I grow into a proficient educator'?

What I'd like to express here is that 'when I grow into a good educator'

Comment: **[Here's the Ngram for all three combinations](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=proficient+educator%2C+competent+educator%2C+accomplished+educator&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccompetent%20educator%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Caccomplished%20educator%3B%2Cc0)** It's a good tool for a proficient learner. (0:

Answer (score 4):

There is a value difference between competent and proficient: While both refer to knowing a skill, competency can refer to the bare minimum required for acceptability. Proficiency carries with it a level of mastery that is above the minimum.

"Competent" lives in an either/or framework . One is either competent or incompetent. Proficiency continues: "I am gaining proficiency in reading".

One can be competent without being spectacular, but continues to grow in his or her proficiency.

Accomplished refers to having a successful track record of achievements.

Answer (score 1):

When you become **proficient** in something, you will then be **competent** and will be able to **accomplish** many things.

**Proficient** is being able **to use a skill**
**Competent** is **knowing** a skill
**Accomplished** is having achieved a high standard ing a skill

> That musician is **competent** and **proficient** but not yet **accomplished**.

**Competency** for educators is usually in some form of **certification**.
Student can review the **proficiency** of their professors on various websites these days.
Professors are considered **accomplished** if they can publish significant research papers.

One can **grow into** larger clothing or a bigger role, but one **becomes** a good educator.

Comment: so 'become' is apt in this context, right? It's just I've already used this word  in my essay, so I was looking for alternatives. And I thought 'grow into' is similar to 'become' since they both indicate the process

Comment: "As I  **grow to become** a good/proficient/useful educator", might be a good transition depending on how you used **become** earlier. Or "once I've **achieved** my certification" might work. These both point int he same direction.

Comment: May I ask that will the word 'develop into' fit here?

Comment: Yes, that would be good